# How do I fix "Ubuntu is running in low-graphics mode?"

Tags: 10.04, xorg, graphics, ati

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix “The system is running in low-graphics mode” error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

First off, I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 on a 30gb partition, the rest of my hdd is for a vista partition. The way I installed this was, I shrunk the vista partition and installed Ubuntu in the largest block of free space. Ubuntu has been working fine for a few weeks, and I've loved it, but today I was doing something in Vista (something simple) and I restarted to go back into ubuntu, and when it tried to boot up I got a message that said: "Ubuntu is running in low-graphics mode. Your screen, graphics card, and input devices could not be detected correctly. You will have to configure these yourself." I click OK, and it gives me a few options but all of them are dead ends. Basically, I'm stuck in CLI right now without a clue of how to fix it. I've tried doing a full update and it hasn't made a difference. I've already been asking for help in #Ubuntu and #Radeon and I was directed by some of them here, so I hope I can find some answers here.

Also, I'm using an ATI Radeon X1200. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Another thing, while I was trying to get help in #radeon I was told that it could possibly be [this bug](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=31154).