# How do I fix “Ubuntu is running in low-graphics mode?” for NVIDIA GeForce GT555M

Tags: nvidia, xorg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix “The system is running in low-graphics mode” error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

As title, I'm using Ubuntu 10.04, and my ubuntu kept showing the sign “Ubuntu is running in low-graphics mode”. I've read another question with same topic ([How do I fix "Ubuntu is running in low-graphics mode?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10664/how-do-i-fix-ubuntu-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode) ), but the other one is using ATI Radeon X1200. How can I fix the problem? I'm running Ubuntu on a 200GB partition, and the rest of my computer is Windows7. My graphic card is NVIDIA GeForce GT 555M, and my computer is ACER ASPIRE 5951G.

Comment: GT 555M has optimus supported. If it is enabled in your laptop try installing bumblebee (http://bumblebee-project.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank @Web-E, that really solve it.
I follow [this page](http://bumblebee-project.org/install.html#Ubuntu) and I ran the following commands to solve this problem.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia
```

Usage:

```
optirun [options] <application> [application-parameters]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your graphics card is an Optimus; it means that you have 2 video cards on your notebook. For that technology Nvidia doesn't have support, than the community is making a way to fix these, but is a little buggy in some systems.

First system is Bumblebee, that in my case didn't work out and you will have to Google the way because I don't now how it works properly.

The second is Ironhide' you can see these forum on Mint community that the process is the same. http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/610

I hope I have helped.
In my notebook a Toshiba F750 i have to install the updates then the Intel graphic works only then I install the Ironhide.

Answer (score 0):

Change the default settings for power management.

Go to System ► Preferences ► Power Management, and change the default **Display** setting to `never`.