# New install ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ati

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix “Ubuntu is running in low-graphics mode?”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10664/how-do-i-fix-ubuntu-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode)

I install Ubuntu 12.04 and obtain the message:

```
The system is running in low graphics mode
Your screen, graphics card and input device settings could not be detected correctly
You will need to reconfigure these yourself.
```

My graphics card is an ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5470
Resolution: 1600x900
Refresh rate: 60Hz

```
lspci | grep VGA 01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RS880M [Mobility Radeon HD 4200 Series] 02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Manhattan [Mobility Radeon HD 5400 Series]

/etc/x11/xorg.conf
bash: /etc/x11/xorg.conf: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
```

Could someone please help me to reconfigure?
I am now using the default (generic) configuration.

I am based in France and speak better French than English.

Comment: On va essayer de t'aider! **;)** S'il-te-plait donne nous le contenu de /etc/X11/xorg.conf, en l'insérant dans ta question **originale** en l'éditant. On va pouvoir t'aider mieux comme ça.

Comment: Oh, as far as I can tell the additonal hardware will show the driver for you to use. The installer seems to have problems with this card. Please expand your question if it does not and I shall delete my reply.

Answer (score 1):

Search for `additional hardware` with `dash` (`windows key`) and check if there is a driver set active. If not activate the most stable one and reboot. This should make Ubuntu start up using better graphics and with Unity as default (and not Unity 2D).

An example of what you need (how it looks like and what options you get probably depends in the card):

[image]

Both drivers in this display are not active. The button on the bottom right activates the chosen driver and will install additional software.

You are going to get 2 additional options in `dash` that should show something like this (how it looks like and what options you get probably depends in the card):

[image]

Comment: Please coud you explain me how to check if there is a driver set active  ? Thanks

Comment: Oh that is easy: see the 1st image and the text bottom left? If it IS active it will show "This drive is active"

Comment: Thank you for your answer Rinzwind ! I have the message These driver is not activited. So I have to click onte button Activate ?

Comment: I clicked on the button but nothing happen ?